# How to get a form to disapear upon submission in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, conditional-statements

This is a 'contact us' form on a website.
I want all the cells of the form to disappear after the user clicks the 'submit' button upon 'success'. In other words, I wont the form to no longer be rendered if the submission is a success. Since this is React, I wouldn't want the page to do an old fashioned reload, just go away upon the condition.
The way it works now upon submission only the button disappears if the submission is a success and nothing disappears if the submission is a failure, which can remain the same.

This is a form that uses XML with a Google Apps Script to send the user's entered form data upon submission. This all works fine and there is something within the 'status' state working with the onSubmit action that is making the Conditional Rendering not so straight forward.

IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO TEST THIS IN REACT TO WORK IT OUT
Since I don't want to put my email code there you should make the 'else' condition that sets 'status' to say 'SUCCESS' near the bottom at 'this.setState({ status: "ERROR" });' so the if/ else in the email sending function (at the bottom) will render the form as if the data went through and the email was sent. My suggestion.

The code below is how the component works normally but my attempt to solve this problem was to store all the cells above  as a variable and 'return' it if 'status' was > 0. Because status is "" before the button is pressed. This just caused the whole page to reload, re-rendering the whole DOM and not sending the email.[image: The form on the site]

```
  import React from 'react';

  export default class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        status: ""
      };
    }
    render() {
      const { status } = this.state;
      return (
        <form
          onSubmit={this.submitForm}
          action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/000000AKfycbz000000000C0/exec"
          method="POST"
        >
              <div className="row_10" style={{"margin-top": "30px"}}>
                <div className="col-25">
                </div>
                <div className="col-75">
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Name:"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row_10">
                <div className="col-25">
                </div>
                <div className="col-75">
                  <input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone:"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row_10">
                <div className="col-25">
                </div>
                <div className="col-75">
                  <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email:"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row_10">
                <div className="col-25">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row_10">
                <div className="col-25">
                </div>
                <div className="row_10">
                  <textarea className="col-75_T" id="subject" name="subject"  placeholder="How can we help you?" style={{"height": "190px"}}></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="subm_button">
                <div className="col-25">
                </div>
                </div>
              {status === "SUCCESS" ? <p>Thank you! We will talk to you soon!</p> :<a href=""><input onClick="fbq('track', 'Contact');" type="submit" value="Submit"/></a>}
              {status === "ERROR" && <p>Ooops! There was an error.</p>}
        </form>
      );
    }
    submitForm(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      const form = ev.target;
      const data = new FormData(form);
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          form.reset();
          this.setState({ status: "SUCCESS" });
        } else {
          this.setState({ status: "ERROR" });
        }
      };
      xhr.send(data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Raw XHR requests, crikey, are you aware of [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: *"The way it works now upon submission only the button disappears if the submission is a success"* - Do you see in your code how that is accomplished?  Did you try applying that same pattern to the rest of the form?

Comment: "_Do you see in your code how that is accomplished?_" No. I wondered about it. I didn't know what was making that happen.

Comment: @David "Did you try applying that same pattern to the rest of the form?" I'm working on it thanks to James' answer. Not working out. Comments below his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the same logic you have with your message to your form

```
renderForm() {
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={this.submitForm}
      action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/000000AKfycbz000000000C0/exec"
      method="POST"
    >
          <div className="row_10" style={{"margin-top": "30px"}}>
            <div className="col-25">
            </div>
            <div className="col-75">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Name:"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row_10">
            <div className="col-25">
            </div>
            <div className="col-75">
              <input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone:"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row_10">
            <div className="col-25">
            </div>
            <div className="col-75">
              <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email:"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row_10">
            <div className="col-25">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row_10">
            <div className="col-25">
            </div>
            <div className="row_10">
              <textarea className="col-75_T" id="subject" name="subject"  placeholder="How can we help you?" style={{"height": "190px"}}></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="subm_button">
            <div className="col-25">
              <a href=""><input onClick="fbq('track', 'Contact');" type="submit" value="Submit"/></a>
            </div>
            </div>
    </form>
  );
}

render() {
  const { status } = this.state;
  const submitted = status === "SUCCESS";
  return (
    <>
      {!submitted && this.renderForm()}
      {submitted && <p>Thank you! We will talk to you soon!</p>}
      {status === "ERROR" && <p>Ooops! There was an error.</p>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is much closer to the solution, but I don't think it's connecting to the function that sends the email through the app. I get 'Ooops! There was an error.' instantly. Something's not waiting for something? I don't know. Also, 'renderForm' doesn't have a capitalized F at the top. Also, I think you wanted a '&&' instead of a '?' in the 'Thank you!' line. My guess. Maybe problem is this line.

Comment: If i move the button to the 'Thank you!' line the page reloads old fashion style and doesn't send an email. It's dilly of a pickle because it doesn't seem to be allowing the form to finish submitting before. You answer similar to what I tried storing form in var. I don't understand it. The line I put the button on ...       {submitted ? <p>Thank you! We will talk to you soon!</p>:<a href=""><input onClick="fbq('track', 'Contact');" type="submit" value="Submit"/></a>}

Comment: @HughMungus the `?` is a mistake, it should be `&&`,this was previously a ternary check but no longer is, just a typo that has been fixed. Same with `renderForm`, capital F should've been on the function above (apologies I wrote this on my mobile device last night and it's terrible for autocorrecting and changing stuff ‍♂️)

Comment: Thanks, @James. But, Like I said, I'm getting an instant 'Oops. There was an error.' If I use your code to move the button outside the function it just reloads the whole page and doesn't send the email. I think something is not connecting. React must be making something happen before the mail sending function can go. Also, your second <> should be a </>.

Comment: Got it working by keeping everything the same but changing the lower <> to </> and changing `{submitted && <p>Thank...` to `{status === "SUCCESS" && ...` I'll give you the green check if you want to update your answer.

Comment: @HughMungus I fixed the missing `</>` earlier, probably the crux of the issue. The second change you made would make no difference `submitted` is set to the result of the same check.

Comment: Hmmm. You're right. I changed it back to your answer and it worked. Must have lost control testing for a solution. Thank you for the answer. Can I ask you to give the question an upvote? I think it was a legit question and I don't want to be banned from asking other ones.

Comment: @HughMungus sure

Comment: Thank you for the thumbs up and answer last week. I've noticed this solution isn't working consistently. At first I thought it was my testing but now I'm sure some of the time the the "SUCCESS" change isn't changing the render. It probably has something to do with the time it takes to send the email. I'm a bit out of my depth, not that I want to keep leaning on you for this. Just sharing the experience. Maybe XML is the wrong thing to be using.

Comment: Reading more on it; it seems like an issue between the 'form' and React. Strange, because the emails always send but today nothing clears from the form cells, nothing disappears after pressing the button.

Comment: One last comment: I think this might be an issue with Chrome because I reverted to the old form that's been working fine for months and the form works on Safari.